# Compartilhamento de Objeto AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Alguem conhece uma forma de enviar um objeto de uma diretiva angular para outra?

Tenho 2 diretivas e preciso ter acesso ao objeto em ambos.

Não estou conseguindo passar por parametro inicialmente já que a função é chamada através de um evento.

Comment: Você pode usar o `$rootScope`.

Comment: você tem algum exemplo de como poderia ser implementado isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lembre-se que services e factories são singletons. Compartilhar objetos pode não ser bom pois, no caso de multiplos usos, os objetos serão sobrescritos a cada chamada, o que pode comprometer o que você deseja mostrar na tela. Exemplo: directive 1 seta o objeto 1, directive 2 sobrescreve e seta o objeto 2. Quando a directive 1 for pegar os dados, vai receber o objeto 2 e não o objeto 1, que seria esperado.

Se for directives em diferentes níveis de hierarquia (parent - child), você pode se basear nesse exemplo para acessar o scope da directive pai através de um filho: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18509399/1481408

Se esse não for seu caso, use o sistema de eventos do angularjs.

Exemplo: para enviar um evento com o objeto em qualquer scope:

`var objeto = { beizer : 'huehuehue' };
$rootScope.$broadcast('pega.o.objeto', objeto);`

na directive que vai receber (scope dentro da função link. Se usar o controller use $scope mesmo):

`scope.$on('pega.o.objeto', function ($event, objeto) {
   ... tá aqui seu objeto  = { beizer : 'huehuehue' }
})`

Answer (score 1):

Compartilhamento de dados pode ser através de serviço.

```
angular.module('app').service('DadosCompartilhados', function() {
  this.dados = {};
});

angular.module('app').directive('diretivaA', function(DadosCompartilhados) {
  // o serviço DadosCompartilhados será compartilhado entre todas as diretivas
  return {
     ...
  };
});
```

Desta forma não se polui nenhum $scope nem exige que as diretivas estejam aninhadas.

**EDIT:**

a intenção é que este serviço seja compartilhado apenas entre as diretivas interessadas. Caso em outro contexto seja necessário compartilhar outros dados (diferentes) crie outro serviço. Nunca reaproveite um serviço para uma tarefa diferente da qual ele foi concebido.

Comment: services são singletons. Compartilhar dessa forma objetos em directives que podem referenciar objetos diferentes vai zuar tudo

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan não entendi o que você refere por "referenciar objetos diferentes". que cenário pode "zuar tudo" ?

Comment: Imagine que alguém chame o service e insira o ObjetoA. Outro lugar seta o ObjetoB. Dessa vez, se alguém que setou o ObjetoA e espera que o retorno seja do tipo ObjetoA, vai receber o ObjetoB. E isso pode comprometer os dados que serão obtidos.

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan simples, ObjetoA é mantido no ServiçoA e ObjetoB é mantido no ServiçoB. não me refiro a criar um serviço único para manter todos os dados da aplicação. Alias um objeto assim já existiria no angular.

Comment: Sim é, é claro. Mas o que eu tinha entendido é que esse seria um service para múltiplos objetos, nesse caso, com um service para cada objeto, funciona OK mesmo.

Comment: Um coisa que funciona legal é ter um service único, mas nos set / get vc passa a chave do objeto que vc quer. Assim fica uma maneira bacana pra gerenciar em um só serviço o que você deseja, como o acesso ao localStorage ou algo assim

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan em contra-partida se perde a habilidade de gerenciar os dados, como validação, transferência, etc. Acredito na criação de serviços apropriados, o sistema fica estruturalmente melhor descrito quando se dá propósitos específicos a cada objeto.